# Codeigniter: Redirect error_general.php errors to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have error produced by `application/views/errors/html/error_general.php`

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> ---
>
> Unable to load the requested file: filename.php

But I want to redirect the error to my controller instead like in my `error_general.php`. Can I do something like?

```
if(substr($message,0,36) == "Unable to load the requested file")
{
    // redirect to my controller
    // $this->My_controller->my_method(); -i don't know what i'm doing here, lol
}
```

Or is there any way to do this?

Comment: can you show us your code so far of the controller?

Comment: what do you mean by redirecting error?  Sending error code from   error_general.php to a controller?

Answer (score 1):

create file `core/MY_Exceptions.php`

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Exceptions extends Exception {

    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500) {
        // do your work here
    }
}
```

refer codeigniter error handling guide for more help.
[codeigniter error handling](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html)